# XML duplicando a leitura dos resultados

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone

Tenho um `XML`:

```
<paises>
<pais>
    <nome-pais>África do Sul</nome-pais>
    <consulados>        
        <consulado>
            <nome-consulado>Consulado da República da África do Sul</nome-consulado>        
            <endereco>Av. Paulista 1754, 12º andar</endereco>       
            <cep>01310-100</cep>
            <telefones>
                <telefone>(11)3265-0449</telefone>
                <telefone>(11)3265-0540</telefone>
            </telefones>
        </consulado>
    </consulados>
</pais>
<pais>
    <nome-pais>Albânia</nome-pais>  
    <consulados>        
        <consulado>
            <nome-consulado>Consulado da República da Albânia</nome-consulado>                  
            <cep>01310-100</cep>
            <telefone>(11) 3283-3305</telefone>
        </consulado>
    </consulados>
</pais>
```

Quando vou ler os telefones, ele sempre duplica:

[image: Duplica a lista]

Código `C#`:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(@"XML\consulados_pt.xml"));
 var result2 = (from p in xmlDoc.Descendants("pais") 
                let Nomepais = p.Element("nome-pais").Value
                from f in xmlDoc.Descendants("telefones")
                                .SelectMany(x=> x.Elements("telefone")
                                .Select(t=>t.Value))
                let telefone = f    
                where Nomepais == SSP.Consulado.pais                
                select new ListaConsulado.Consulado()
                    {
                        NomePais = Nomepais,
                        Telefone = "Tel: " + telefone
                    }
                ).ToList();
```

obs: coloquei esse código `let telefone = f` só pra testes!

- Eu queria pegar os 2 telefones, sem duplicar a lista
- E tem outro detalhe, quando abro outra item da lista, ele traz esses
  mesmo telefones:

[image: Mesmos telefones]

```
<telefone>(11)3265-0449</telefone>
<telefone>(11)3265-0540</telefone>
```

`XAML em caso de dúvidas`

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="lstCons"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    LayoutMode="List" 
    IsGroupingEnabled="False"
    Width="456" SelectionChanged="lstCons_SelectionChanged" >
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#111" Background="Transparent" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
                            <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical"  >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomeConsulado}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Endereco}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cep}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Telefone}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na atribuição `telefone = f.Element("telefone").Value`, pois o método `Element` retorna apenas um elemento, que no caso será o primeiro que for encontrado.

Ao invés disso, use o método `Elements`, e o método do LINQ `SelectMany` para poder criar a lista com os telefones:

```
var result2 = xmlDoc.Descendants("telefones")
    .SelectMany(
        x => x.Elements("telefone")
            .Select(t => t.Value))
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

No caso poderia usar o seguinte, para obter cada consulado, com o nome do pais correspondente, e os respectivos telefones:

```
var consuladosComTelefones = xmlDoc
    .Element("paises")
    .Elements("pais")
    .SelectMany(
        p => p.Element("consulados") == null ? null : p.Element("consulados")
            .Elements("consulado")
            .Select(c => new ListaConsulado.Consulado
            {
                NomePais = p.Element("nome-pais").Value,
                Telefone = c.Element("telefones") == null ? null : c.Element("telefones")
                    .Elements("telefone")
                    .Select(t => t.Value).ToList(),
            })).ToList();
```

Admitindo-se que a classe consulado esteja assim:

```
public class Consulado
{
    public string NomePais { get; set; }
    public List<string> Telefone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Editei a resposta, usando consulta estruturada no XDocument usando os métodos `Element` e `Elements`, além dos métodos `Select` e `SelectMany` do LINQ. Assim a leitura do XML fica mais bem estruturada... eu acho.

Comment: Tá retornando o seguinte erro: `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Digitei o nome da propriedade errado! Corrigido... também coloquei algumas verificações caso o XML esteja incompleto.